# numpy - Change/Specify dtypes of masked array columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types, masked-array

I have a csv-file containing a lot of data that I want to read as a masked array. I've done so using the following:

```
data=np.recfromcsv(filename,case_sensitive=True,usemask=True)
```

which works just fine. However, my problem is that the data are either strings, integers, or floats. What I want to do now is convert all the integers into floats, i.e. turn all the "1"s into "1.0"s etc. while preserving everything else.

Additionally, I am looking for a generic solution. So simply specifying the desired types manually won't do since the csv-file (including the number of columns) changes.

I've tried *astype* but since the array also has string-entries that won't work, or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used `recfromcsv`, but looking at its code I see it uses `np.genfromtxt`, followed by a masked records construction.

I'd suggest giving a small sample `csv` text (3 or so lines), and show the resulting `data`.  We need to see the `dtype` in particular.

It may also be useful to start with `genfromtxt`, skipping the masked array stuff for now.  I don't think that's where the sticky point is in converting dtypes in structured arrays.

In any case, we need something more concrete to explore.

You can't change the `dtype` of structured fields in-place.  You have to make a new array with a new dtype, and copy values from the old to the new.

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf
```

has some functions that can help in changing structured arrays.

===========

I suspect that it will be simpler to spell out the `dtypes` when calling `genfromtxt` than to change dtypes in an existing array.

You could try one read with the `dtype=None` and limited number of lines to get the column count and base `dtype`.  Then edit that, substituting floats for ints as needed.  Now read the whole with the new dtype.  Look in the `recfunctions` code if you need ideas on how to edit dtypes.

For example:

```
In [504]: txt=b"""a, 1, 2, 4\nb, 6, 9, 10\nc, 4, 4, 3"""

In [506]: arr = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), dtype=None, delimiter=',')
In [507]: arr
Out[507]: 
array([(b'a', 1, 2, 4), (b'b', 6, 9, 10), (b'c', 4, 4, 3)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S1'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4')])
In [508]: arr.dtype.descr
Out[508]: [('f0', '|S1'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4')]
```

A crude dtype editor:

```
def foo(tup):
    name, dtype=tup
    dtype = dtype.replace('S','U')
    dtype = dtype.replace('i','f')
    return name, dtype
```

And applying this to default dtype:

```
In [511]: dt = [foo(tup) for tup in arr.dtype.descr]
In [512]: dt
Out[512]: [('f0', '|U1'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f4')]

In [513]: arr = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), dtype=dt, delimiter=',')
In [514]: arr
Out[514]: 
array([('a', 1.0, 2.0, 4.0), ('b', 6.0, 9.0, 10.0), ('c', 4.0, 4.0, 3.0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<U1'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f4')])

In [522]: arr = np.recfromcsv(txt.splitlines(), dtype=dt, delimiter=',',case_sensitive=True,usemask=True,names=None)
In [523]: arr
Out[523]: 
masked_records(
    f0 : ['a' 'b' 'c']
    f1 : [1.0 6.0 4.0]
    f2 : [2.0 9.0 4.0]
    f3 : [4.0 10.0 3.0]
    fill_value : ('N', 1.0000000200408773e+20, 1.0000000200408773e+20, 1.0000000200408773e+20)
              )
```

=====================

`astype` works if the target dtype matches.  For example if I read the `txt` with dtype=None, and then use the derived `dt`, it works:

```
In [530]: arr = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=',',dtype=None)
In [531]: arr
Out[531]: 
array([(b'a', 1, 2, 4), (b'b', 6, 9, 10), (b'c', 4, 4, 3)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S1'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4')])
In [532]: arr.astype(dt)
Out[532]: 
array([('a', 1.0, 2.0, 4.0), ('b', 6.0, 9.0, 10.0), ('c', 4.0, 4.0, 3.0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<U1'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f4')])
```

Same for `arr.astype('U3,int,float,int')` which also has 4 compatible fields.